# How to cancel a download request when cancel button pressed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I want to cancel the download request when i press the cancel button.
Now when i press download button following code works

```
@IBAction func downloadButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {            
                var fileName = noticeAttacchment[0]["fileName"] as! String
                var fileUrl =  noticeAttacchment[0]["fileUrl"] as! String
                if var URL = NSURL(string: fileUrl){
                    Api.load(URL, fileName: fileName)      
                }
    }
```

And my downloader class is

```
 class Api {
    class func load(URL: NSURL , fileName : String) {
                let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
                let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
                request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
                let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        FileSave.saveData(
                            data, directory: NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, path: fileName, subdirectory: "edstem")
                    }
                    else {
                        println("Faulure: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }
    }
```

So how to cancel the request when cancel button pressed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `load()` function needs to `return` the `NSURLSessionDataTask` you created. You then call `task.cancel()` to cancel the request

additional [Reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-2--mobile-21581)

Comment: How this possible please explain?

Comment: `dataTaskWithRequest(_:)` returns `NSURLSessionDataTask` which you already have in your task variable. So you'd call `task.cancel()` the same way you call `task.resume()`. Is it clear now?