# URLSessionDownloadTask: Cancel writing data

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

I am working on an application that takes a few minutes to download a large file and write that to disk. The client has informed me that they wish to be able to cancel this at any time. What I have done is encapsulate a global `URLSession` that will handle the download task. Following user input I will call `invalidateAndCancel()` on the session. I have found that the method

```
urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
        downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,    
        didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, 
   totalBytesWritten: Int64, 
   totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
```

does not stop being called even after the session has been invalidated and cancelled.

**QUESTION**

How to I get this method to stop executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Previous Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002133/how-to-cancel-a-download-request-when-cancel-button-pressed-in-swift)

Try the link above I think it explains it better than I can. Also [Another Reference](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-2--mobile-21581)

Comment: Umm... no.  The `invalidateAndCancel` method cancels all tasks within a given session (hence "cancel").  Per the documentation, you should *never* get additional delegate calls after you call that method (or at most a few milliseconds afterwards to account for multithreading).  If that isn't what you're seeing, then either you aren't canceling the right session, your task isn't in that session, or you have found a very serious bug.